# Can Maven pull the dependency into the project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven-3

I am working on a number of small projects with Eclipse, Spring, Java and Tomcat using Subversion for version control.  I am looking to try to use Maven for the first time but one thing I see already that I don't like is that if I start a project with maven it will download all the dependency into my `.m2` folder and all the class path to the projects but we like to have all the dependency moved into `WEB-INF/lib` so we can check them into Subversion.

Can this be done with Maven? Should it be done this way?

Comment: Why do you need to commit dependencies into a source repository?

Comment: So that you can rebuild your project at a moments notice from just the repository. It's crucial to getting new hires able to build the system without much hassle.

Comment: I'll offer a different opinion, that what you're trying to do is actually preferred for many projects up to a certain complexity and/or team size. I've built numerous Java applications, from command-line to desktop UI, to JEE and other web apps, and managed the dependencies manually like you describe. I've also worked on several maven-driven projects. I can say without a doubt that the explicit, method (including dependencies directly in the project) is far easier to set up and maintain, IMO. Maven, to me, is a big example of a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: For very simple and lightweight Eclipse dependency management solution basing on Maven Eclipse Plugin see my answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122614/very-lightweight-eclipse-maven-integration-dependency-management-only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking in binary packages into your source control isn't really ideal, and goes against the grain with maven. A valid concern is what happens when those online repositories go down and the solution is to host your own repository using something like [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php). Some people don't like that they have to maintain another system along side with the source control, but it's worth it to get all the features that maven brings to the table.

Comment: Binaries in a source repo is a big mistake, especially when you become enlightened and move to a distributed SCM like git or bzr, one that downloads the entire repo history.

Comment: I could not disagree more. Java dependencies (JARs) do not change very often, so the" downloads the entire history" argument doesn't hold water.

Comment: But they do change quite frequently, that you decide not to update to a newer versions is another matter.

Comment: "Some people don't like that they have to maintain another system along side with the source control" - one can always go with the SaaS offering - zero maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

You can download dependencies with aid of Maven (e.g. by using the [maven-dependeny-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html)), but most certainly you do not want to do that.

From [Why not Store JARs in CVS?](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#Why_not_Store_JARs_in_CVS) (or any other version control system):

- It uses less storage - while a repository is typically quite large, because each JAR is only kept in the one place it is actually saving space, even though it may not seem that way
- It makes checking out a project quicker - initial checkout, and to a small degree updating, a project will be faster if there are no large binary files in CVS. While they may need to be downloaded again afterwards anyway, this only happens once and may not be necessary for some common JARs already in place.
- No need for versioning - CVS and other source control systems are designed for versioning files, but external dependencies typically don't change, or if they do their filename changes anyway to indicate the new version. Storing these in CVS doesn't have any added benefit over keeping them in a local artifact cache.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to understand about Maven is that dependencies of a project should not be checked in into version control (does not depend on which version control). The idea of Maven is to have the dependencies only in a single place $HOME/.m2/repository. This means for every project you are working you have only the dependencies an single time on your hard drive. The dependency management makes it easy to add/change/remove dependencies from your project. Furthermore Maven **will not only** handle dependencies it will support you in doing **unit/integration testing**, creation of **reporting** like **code-coverage** etc. and much more. If you really thinking of working with Maven you should set up a Repository Manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva.

The most important point is if you don't like the way Maven works that get the your fingers off from Maven otherwise you will loose the challenge. If you like to work with maven you have to accept the **Maven Way**.